# Flutter & Firebase - Get a specific field from document

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have been trying to get a specific field from a specific document. I need token for toWho. But I always got null. How do I fix this?

Main Code is

```
Future<String> getUserToken(String toWho) async {
    DocumentSnapshot _doc = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.doc("tokens/" + toWho).get();
    if (_doc != null) {
      Map<String, dynamic> _data = _doc.data();
      return _data["token"];
    } else {
      return null;
    }
}
```

in Repository

```
Future<bool> sendMessage(
      MessageModel sendingMessage, UserModel currentUser) async {
    if (appMode == AppMode.DEBUG) {
      return true;
    } else {
      var _writePrcs = await _firestoreDBService.saveMessage(sendingMessage);
      if (_writePrcs) {
        var _token = "";
        if (_userToken.containsKey(sendingMessage.toWho)) {
          _token = _userToken[sendingMessage.toWho];
          print("Token lokalden geldi.");
        } else {
          _token = await _firestoreDBService.getUserToken(sendingMessage.toWho);
          _userToken[sendingMessage.toWho] = _token;

          print("Token  veritabanından geldi.");
        }
```

Thanks for your help from now on

[image: start of my firestore]

[image: i need to get token that i highligted]

Answer (score 0):

```
Try ........... 


 Future<String> getUserToken(String toWho) async {
    DocumentSnapshot _doc = await 
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("tokens/groupChatId/message").doc(toWho).get();
      if (_doc != null) {
         Map<String, dynamic> _data = _doc.data();
         return _data["token"];
      } else {
        return null;
   }
}
```

Comment: Tried but got same ----[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null. E/flutter (10259): Receiver: null E/flutter (10259): Tried calling: []("token")

Comment: Send a screenshot of your Firestore structure

Comment: added structures

Comment: there is no field called token. in "messages"